# How to fix width bug in HTML5?

Tags: css, html

I am writing an HTML5 page but there is a weird bug in Chrome 16.0.912.77 and FireFox 7.01 where the first element to get a px based width (in this case ".container") gets a much smaller pixel width (500px) than what I originally specified. (1000px)

See snapshot of the error here:

http://i42.tinypic.com/bj8kd5.png

The interesting thing is that when I run the exact same markup in JSFiddle, it works as expected. HTML sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/TWDKa/

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you link to a page where the problem *does* occur?

Comment: nevermind, i had my browser zoomed out. DOH! Thanks to Paul Irish for kindly pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> in Chrome to zoom out. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, the browser was zoomed out. DOH!